# gráfico em 3d com erro de dimensão

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Estou tentando plotar um gráfico em 3d. Eu já tenho em 2d. Tudo tranquilo aí.

É uma matriz com os valores das amplitudes de um onda propagando em um guia. Mas gostaria de plotar os valores da matriz como 'alturas'.

No código abaixo, as dimensões da matriz original são `len(vals) = 333` e `len(vals[2]) = 116`.

Para a linha que começa com `surf = ax.plot_surface...`, o erro que aparece é o seguinte:

```
ValueError: Shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

```
xx, yy = np.mgrid[1:333, 1:116]
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(13,7))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(xx, yy, vals2[100], rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap='RdBu', edgecolor='none')
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('Intensity')
ax.set_title('Wave propagation inside waveguide')
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)  # add color bar
ax.view_init(60,35)
plt.savefig('figuraTeste3d.png', format='png')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Os arrays de x, y e z têm que ter o mesmo shape.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d

xx = np.arange(-5,5,0.25)
xx,yy = np.meshgrid(xx,xx)
zz = np.random.random(xx.shape);

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(13,7))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(xx, yy, zz, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap='RdBu', edgecolor='none')
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('Intensity')
ax.set_title('Wave propagation inside waveguide')
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)  # add color bar
ax.view_init(60,35)
plt.savefig('figuraTeste3d.png', format='png')
plt.show()
```